# Как запускать программу через файл и читать его?

Tags: java

Есть файл bla.test, нужно чтобы когда я на него нажимал он открывал мою программу и в ней считывался этот файл.

У меня такое ощущение что это делается через String []args но я не знаю как передать в нее расположение файла через который запускается приложение.

Comment: Уточните ОС - Windows ?

Comment: @Kromster Да Windows

Comment: Добавьте соответствующую метку в вопрос. По идее это называется ассоциированием типа файлов с программой.